# Jquery input :checked show and hide div function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to create a simple JQuery function. This function has three check boxes and a compare button. Example can be  [Seen here](https://jsfiddle.net/862hd4o1/3/)

The objective of this function is when the user clicks on checkboxes 1 and 2 it compares the content of hidden containers one and two. When users clicks on checkboxes 1 and 3 it compares the content of hidden containers one and three.

I can't get this function get this working. I added a snippet of code below

```js
   

 $(document).ready(function() {
   var $checkboxes = $('[name^="check"]');
   var $target = $('#target');
   var $button = $('.compare');

   $button.on('click', function() {
    $('.data').hide();
    $('.checkBox:checked').each(function() {
     var div = $(this).attr('name');
     $('.compare-block').find('.'+div).show();
    })
  })
 })
```

Comment: First thing I notice is that you define a $checkboxes but don't actually use it and there's a quite a few ; missing. Is this all the code?

Comment: Your snipet gives an error ""message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined". Please add it properly.

Comment: Additionally, you are counting the number of checkboxes that are checked, but you don't track which ones (what happens if I check 2 and 3). With this example there's also a check for four checked boxes while there are only three on the page according to the description.

Answer (score 0):

I changed a bit your snippet. You are using only the length, but if you want to compare 1 and 3 or X and Y, you need to know wich ones are selected.

The changed I did, first you check if there is more than one to compare, and then, you see wich ones. I edited a bit the HTML to add some ids

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $button  = $('.compare');

  $button.on('click', function() {
    var checkedLength = $('[name^="check"]:checked').length;
    $('#target .compare-block').hide();
    if (checkedLength > 1 ) {
      $( '[name^="check"]:checked' ).each(function() {
        //$(this).val() I use value, but you can use another thing
        $('#container'+$(this).val()).show();
      });
    }
  })
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t95kgzvx/4/